# React style object, adding styling for specific classes

Tags: reactjs

Ok so this is the widget (it renders things fine, generally).

```
const Widget = props => {
    console.log(props);
    let s = {...props.style}
    s.gridColumn = `span `+props.width;
    s.gridRow = `span `+props.height;       

    return (        
    <div className="widget" style={s}>
        {props.content}
    </div>
    );
}
```

Basically it draws the div the grid column sizes I have in the props, so far so good. It also respects the style object I pass to it if it looks like this.

```
  let widgetstyle1 = { 
    backgroundColor: "white"
}

<Widget height={2} width={4} content={widgetcontent1} style={widgetstyle1}/>
```

The tricky part comes if I want my widget style to allow for classes inside the content.

In that case the content looks like this:

```
const widgetcontent2 = <p>pomo<span className="round">34</span>na</p>
```

I've tried this

```
  let widgetstyle1 = { 
    backgroundColor: "white",
    round: {
      color:"green"
    }  

  }
```

And it compiles, but my number span isn't green, and I have tried this:

```
  let widgetstyle1 = { 
    backgroundColor: "white",
    #round: {
      color:"green"
    }  

  }
```

Which refuses to compile.

I just need the way to tell the javascript object class and id specific formatting inside of that object for react. I understand I could pass the style.round to my widget, but I only want it to apply the style to appropriately named classes.

This seems straightforward, I'm just not querying quite the right terms.

Comment: Could you include a [mre]? Creating a React StackSnippet can be done by following [these meta steps](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, when you want to apply styles to specific classes inside the content, you should use the `className` prop instead of trying to nest styles directly within the style object. The `style` prop is typically used for inline styles, and it doesn't support targeting specific classes or IDs within the content.

Here's how you can modify your `Widget` component to handle this:

```
const Widget = props => {
    console.log(props);
    let s = { ...props.style };
    s.gridColumn = `span ` + props.width;
    s.gridRow = `span ` + props.height;

    return (
        <div className="widget" style={s}>
            {React.cloneElement(props.content, {
                style: { ...props.content.props.style, ...props.style },
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Now, when you use the `Widget` component, you can pass the styles for specific classes using the `style` prop:

```
let widgetstyle1 = {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    color: "blue", // Apply a style to the overall content
    round: {
        color: "green", // Apply a style to the class "round"
    },
};

const widgetcontent2 = <p style={{ color: "red" }}>pomo<span className="round">34</span>na</p>;

<Widget height={2} width={4} content={widgetcontent2} style={widgetstyle1} />;
```

In this example, the `color: "blue"` in `widgetstyle1` will apply a style to the overall content, and `color: "green"` within `round` will apply a style specifically to the class "round" inside the content. Note that inline styles provided directly to the content will also be merged with the styles from the `Widget` component.

Answer (score 3):

You can't target CSS classes using inline CSS.

When inlining a style object into a HTML element, React will strip out those invalid properties:

```
const styles = {
  fontSize: '16px',
  someInvalidProperty: {
    color: "green"
  }
}

// React:
<div style={styles}></div>

// HTML Output:
<div style="font-size: 16px"></div>
```

One approach would be to use a CSS-in-JS library like `styled-components` and you could achieve what you're after using something like:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import "./styles.css";

const widgetContent = (
  <p>
    pomo<span className="round">34</span>na
  </p>
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Widget
        height={2}
        width={4}
        content={widgetContent}
        contentStyles={`.round { color: green }`}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const Widget = ({ height, width, content, contentStyles }) => {
  // Any Widget specific logic here
  return (
    <WidgetStyled height={height} width={width} contentStyles={contentStyles}>
      {content}
    </WidgetStyled>
  );
};

const WidgetStyled = styled.div`
  grid-column: span ${(props) => props.width};
  grid-row: span ${(props) => props.height};

  // Option 1:
  // Pass CSS in using contentStyles prop in <Widget />
  ${(props) => props.contentStyles};

  // Option 2:
  // If the CSS for .round doesn't need to change you can uncomment the below and remove the code for Option 1 (i.e. any mention of 'contentStyles')
  // .round {
  //   color: green;
  // }
`;
```

Working example:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/so77896494-mr3gx8

Answer (score 3):

You can you emotion CSS source: https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction

```
import React from 'react';
import { css } from '@emotion/css';

const Widget = (props) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={css`
       ${props.style}
       grid-column: span ${(props) => props.width};
       grid-row: span ${(props) => props.height};
       padding: 100px;
       .round {
         color: red;
       }
    `}
      // style={s}
    >
      {props.content}
    </div>
  );
};

let widgetstyle1 = css`
  background-color: #ddd;
  .round {
    color: green!important;
  }
`;

const widgetcontent1 = (
  <p>
    pomo<span className="round">34</span>na
  </p>
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Widget
        height={2}
        width={4}
        content={widgetcontent1}
        style={widgetstyle1}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I like this better than my answer but @WestMountain could you update the answer to include a code example for OP question?

Comment: Here is the stackblit link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-refhsd?file=src%2FApp.js
Basically same with your styled-component solution

Answer (score 2):

You can make widgetstyle1 nested object, and then in js loop over all content children with css classname "round" and add to their style your widgetstyle1.round.

```
let widgetstyle1 = {
  root:{
    backgroundColor: "white",
  }
  round: {
    color:"green"
  }  
}
```